# selfmade vector template operator[] error

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I have made my own vector template, `operator[]` part of it :

```
template <class T>
T& vector<T>::operator[](unsigned int index)
{
    return m_Data[index];
}
```

I use this code in class copy constructor

```
Track::Track(const Track& src)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < src.sorted.size(); i++)
        AddCar(src.sorted[i]->rz, src.sorted[i]->owners.back()->name, src.sorted[i]->owners.back()->surname);
}
```

and I am getting an error `'no match for operator[] (operands types are const vector<Track*> and unsigned int)'`

I tried to overload `operator[]` with `const` keyword:

```
const T& operator[](unsigned int);
```

but that gave me a different error: `const T& operator[](unsigned int); cannot be overloaded`

What could be the cause here?

Comment: What was that another error?

Comment: I guess you should be returning `const T&` when you add `const `modifier to your `operator[]`, and that was your second error

Comment: i tried this const T& operator[](unsigned int); compiler says "const T&                  operator[](unsigned int); cannot be overloaded"

Comment: @lllook *...when you add const modifier to your operator[]...*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to implement a `const` version of `operator[]` like this:

```
template <class T>
const T& vector<T>::operator[](unsigned int index) const
{
    return m_Data[index];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The cause is exactly what you said: there's no `const` overload, so you can't apply `[]` to a `const` vector.

You don't say what you tried or what the error was, but this should work:

```
T const & operator[](unsigned int index) const {return m_Data[index];}    
T       & operator[](unsigned int index)       {return m_Data[index];}
```